# What is the best overall youth / first team training camp in Fifa Manager 11?

Tags: fifa-manager-2011

With so many choices I'm not sure what to choose. Which camp is the overall best one for the youth team and first team in Fifa Manager?

Comment: The term "best" can be quite subjective. Can you edit your question to include what specific characteristics you're looking for? Otherwise, it's difficult to answer.

Comment: What's hard to understand about "best overall"? I'm not looking for specifics or I would've asked about it. I'm looking for a best overall camp which covers everything as good as possible.